# TexLive Version used by TexStudio

Tags: 12.04, latex

I have installed texlive 2013 over the internet.

I followed the documentation given along with it to set the PATH variables post installation. I needed some tex editor. So i decided to install TexStudio through synapic package manager. When it was downloading the packages required, i noticed that it was also installing texlive 2012 related packages from launchpad:ppa:backports.

---

Now my question is that when i am using a package in texstudio while writing a file, am i using that of texlive 2012 or texlive 2013?

---

**(PS tex --version in the terminal shows Texlive 2013.)**

Answer (score 0):

You are using Texlive 2013. As you know based on your question - To know the version, use this command in the terminal:

```
tex --version
```